# How do I load a component inside a class that extends BaseAuthenticate in CakePHP?

Tags: authentication, cakephp, components, cakephp-2.x, cakephp-2.7

I have created my own authenticator which handles OAuth 2:

```
class OauthAuthenticate extends BaseAuthenticate
```

I would like to use a custom component (extended from `Component`) in my `OauthAuthenticate` class.

How can I to load my component there? The traditional

```
public $components = array('OauthAuthenticate');
```

doesn't work - the component is not loaded.

Comment: Components can be used in another component, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BaseAuthenticate` class cannot load component via `$components` array as is usual in controllers, but loading a component is possible in constructor:

```
private $utilComponent = null;

    public function __construct(ComponentCollection $collection, array $settings)
    {
        $this->utilComponent = $collection->load('Util');
    }
```

Comment: Let the downvoter explains what is wrong with this solution. See CakePHP documentation - http://api.cakephp.org/2.7/class-ComponentCollection.html#_load